# Testing a JSON PUT request in mojolicious

Tags: perl, testing, mojolicious

I am creating test cases for my app developed using Mojolicious framework. I am testing the routes for appropriate responses for the REST calls that are made. I use JSON as a means of communication between the server and client. To test `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests I use the following functions

`GET : get_ok()`
`POST: post_json_ok()`
 `DELETE: delete_ok()`

but for `PUT` I am not able to use `put_ok()`. And example of my usage of put_ok() would be 
 `my $t = Test::Mojo->new;`
`$t->put_ok('this/is/url/to/resource'=>{ "element" => "modified value"})->status_is(204)`

I get a bad request status every time(400) and so the test fails. I use `Test::Mojo` for testing my application.

Additional information:

`$t->put_ok('http://localhost:3000/application/instances/system/test'=>{"model" => "testing put"})->status_is(204);`

 
 This is the exact test for `PUT` request that is attempted.
 `model` is a property of resource `test` that is being attempted to be changed to `testing put` and the expected status response is `204`.

The mapping to the controller is done by 
`$r->route('/application/instances/system/:id, id  => qr/[A-Za-z0-9 ]+/ -> via('put')
    ->to(controller => 'system', action => 'update_sys');`

 This route calls the `update_sys` method in the `system` controller and that is how the resource is located.

Comment: I don't see a `put_ok` in there, I see a `get_ok`.

Comment: @Bill Ruppert <br> [this link](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Mojo) has the explanation for `put_ok`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, after discussions with SRI on IRC, he pointed me to an example almost identical you your needs in the [documentation](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo).

```
# Test custom transaction
my $tx = $t->ua->build_json_tx('/user/99' => {name => 'sri'});
$tx->req->method('PUT');
$t->tx($t->ua->start($tx))
  ->status_is(200)
  ->json_is('/message' => 'User has been replaced.');
```

So this should work for you!

**Postscript:**

You might be interested to know that this discussion has brought some progress: the next release of Mojolicious (version 3.66) will now have a cleaner syntax for this purpose, the new [`request_ok`](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo#request_ok) method. The above example can then be rewritten as

```
my $tx = $t->ua->build_json_tx('/user/99' => {name => 'sri'});
$tx->req->method('PUT');
$t->request_ok($tx)
  ->status_is(200)
  ->json_is('/message' => 'User has been replaced.');
```

Comment: Thank you @Joel, this is exactly what I was looking for. Looking forward to the request_ok method as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: [3.66](https://metacpan.org/release/SRI/Mojolicious-3.66/) has been released! `request_ok` to your heart's content!

Comment: This answer recently got upvoted so I thought I would comment. All request type test methods can use [content generators](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Content-generators) now, so have at 'em!

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the definition of your route for 'this/is/url/to/resource' ?  the server is returning 400, so it appears Mojo::Controller in your app does not understand what you are sending ...

Comment: I can assure you that my controller does understand what I am sending. Without this test if I use a REST client to modify any resource with `PUT`, I am able to do it and I do not get a 400 response. Only when I use the `TEST::Mojo` module to test the `PUT` request do I get the error. 

Could you please elaborate on definition of the routes? Do you mean how code of how the routes are mapped to controller or do you want the actual route itself. What ever be the case, I am certain the routes are defined properly.

Comment: i meant for you to show us the method this route was mapped to in the controller.  when asking for help, it usually is helpful for the OP to show the code that corresponds to the given problem.  Since your call to the supposed put_ok looked fine, those expected to give help usually need additional information.  Taking these things on faith and assurances usually lead to waste of time, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you @Paul, I added additional information after your suggestion.